# How to resolve 'react-native-crypto-js' sha256 undefined error

Tags: react-native, cryptojs

Here's what I did.

I installed `react-native-crypto-js` with following command and then I tested it using their example.

```
npm install react-native-crypto-js
    
var SHA256 = require("react-native-crypto-js").SHA256;
console.log(SHA256("Message"));
```

But I'm getting an error: sha256 is not a function

Comment: it shouldn't show it's not a function if you are just using the code above. Did you encounter error when installing, did u add other codes? where are you using these codes?

Comment: no. it installed correctly.
and below example is working. But I need to create a hash.

import CryptoJS from "react-native-crypto-js";
 
// Encrypt
let ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123').toString();

Comment: where did you come across the above example? because i couldnt find it. and would this work `var SHA256 = require("react-native-crypto-js"); console.log(SHA256.SHA256("Message"));` ?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem with the same code. Please let me know any solution

Comment: same...Has anyone cracked CryptoJS.HmacSHA256 in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/imchintan/react-native-crypto-js), SHA256 is not implemented.
The only algorithms implemented are MD5, HmacMD5, and AES.

Also, as of writing this, react-native-crypto-js has not been updated in 5 years. For these two reasons, I moved to [react-native-quick-crypto](https://github.com/margelo/react-native-quick-crypto)